# Configure.Await(false) with fire and forget async calls

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Currently in my console application, I do the following to delete files in fire and forget style.

I was wondering if there is any performance gain in setting `ConfigureAwait(false)` for each of these `Task.Run` calls?

(My assumption is no, since I am not awaiting the call but I am not sure)

```
 for(var file in files)
  '
  '
  // Check for certain file condition and decide to delete it. 
  '
  '
  if(shouldDeleteFile)
  {
    Task.Run(() => File.Delete(file));
  }
```

Comment: As far as I know, Console Apps don't have a synchronization context. I don't suspect `ConfigureAwait(false)` would do much of anything.

Comment: @JonathonChase That's correct. Using `ConfigureAwait(false)` will not have any impact here

Comment: its correct, `ConfigureAwait(false)` has no power here, though if this code might be used in a library at some point then its probably worth while. As to performance in your console app, you would have to check the code, maybe you will save a couple of IL statements because of a short cut, but its debatable

Comment: ConfigureAwait true means continue from same thread that started awaiting, if you set that to false it can continue from any other thread (or same thread) after await.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ConfigureAwait(false)` would not do anything here, because there is no `await` to configure.

It's "configure await", not "configure task".

Answer (score 4):

It is self-explanatory if you look at the signature of the method itself:

```
public ConfiguredTaskAwaitable ConfigureAwait (bool continueOnCapturedContext);
```

the argument is `continueOnCapturedContext`, it is a **continuation** but you said you are doing your job in fire and forget manner, you are not doing `await`. Conclusion, there is no effect since you do not have any **continuation**.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: NO,

> There’s one common kind of application that doesn’t have a
>   SynchronizationContext: console apps. When your console application’s
>   Main method is invoked, SynchronizationContext.Current will return
>   null. That means that if you invoke an asynchronous method in your
>   console app, unless you do something special, your asynchronous
>   methods will not have thread affinity: the continuations within those
>   asynchronous methods could end up running “anywhere.”

Source : ["Await, SynchronizationContext, and Console Apps"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/)